# What exactly is the age category modifier for a dragon's Frightful Presence ability?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dragons

The Frightful Presence ability description says:

> Frightful Presence (Ex)
>
> A young adult or older dragon can unsettle foes with its mere presence. The ability takes effect automatically whenever the dragon attacks, charges, or flies overhead. Creatures within a radius of 30 feet × the dragon’s age category are subject to the effect if they have fewer HD than the dragon. A potentially affected creature that succeeds on a Will save (DC 10 + ½ dragon’s HD + dragon’s Cha modifier) remains immune to that dragon’s frightful presence for 24 hours. On a failure, creatures with 4 or less HD become panicked for 4d6 rounds and those with 5 or more HD become shaken for 4d6 rounds. Dragons ignore the frightful presence of other dragons.

Dragons have age categories ranging from a wyrmling to the great wyrm. What number should be used to calculate the range of Frightful Presence ability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Follow the sequence in the tables

You use their age category, ranked from *Wyrmling* to *Great Wyrm*, in sequence:

1. Wyrmling
2. Very young
3. Young
4. Juvenile
5. Young adult
6. Adult
7. Mature Adult
8. Old
9. Very old
10. Ancient
11. Wyrm
12. Great Wyrm

This can be seen on the existing dragons in the *Monster Manual*. The very old red dragon's *Frightful Presence*, for instance, has a **270-ft** radius, exactly **30 * 9**;